Creating SharePoint folder with "title" property via Boomi
How would I populate the "title" property of a SharePoint folder when creating the folder via Boomi (with an HTTP request)?
I can't seem to find the full JSON to do this.
This is all I have now:

Thanks.
Paul

The folder name is the last part of ServerRelativeUrl. There is no Title for a folder. Only a document can have a title distinct from the file path name.
ServerRelativeUrl is the path with the library name.
Example:
/document library relative url/folder name
Complete HTTP request:
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/folders
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
Content-Type: "application/json"
Content-Length: {length of request body as integer}
X-RequestDigest: "{form_digest_value}"

{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Folder"
  },
  "ServerRelativeUrl": "/document library relative url/folder name"
}

Source: Working with folders by using REST

Thanks for the reply.  I am being told that the folder name is not the same as the folder "title".  Are there other properties that can be set at folder creation time?  Perhaps under __metadata, besides the "type"?  I do not have the full JSON.

I did find attribute/property for "Title" of a folder, using: /_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/[folder name]')/ListItemAllFields  .  Now just need to play with updating it.

There is no Title for a folder. Only a document can have a title distinct from the file path name.
